# How define server variable into javascript context?

Tags: javascript, jsp, variables

When I have a variable defined into server context, sometimes I need use it into javascript context; for example the session id.

**What's the better way to do it?**

I want to **separate** javascript files and view files (in my case `jsp`); for the moment I have found 2 ways:

**1**) `myVariables.js.jsp`: create a jsp file that returns javascript code

```
myLib = {
    sessionID: "${sessionId}",
    [...]
}
```

and import it as javascript into the jsp view file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="myVariables.js.jsp"></script>
        [...]
    </head>
<body>
[...]
</body>
</html>
```

I'm able to get the session id writing: `myLib.sessionId`.

**Pros**: handy and rapid.

**Cons**: write a `jsp` file that acts as `js`.

**2**) Save the server variable into hidden input fields (for example, in the main part of the template):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="myLib.js"></script>
        [...]
    </head>
<body>
<form id="myVariables">
    <input type="hidden" name="sessionId" value="${sessionId}" />
    [...]
</form>
[...]
</body>
</html>
```

I'm able to get the session id writing a specific function into `myLib.js` library:

```
myLib = {
    sessionId: function() {
        return $("form#myVariables > input[name=sessionId]").val();
    },
    [...]
}
```

**Pros**: javascript and view completely separated.

**Cons**: more code to write; little harder to understand than the previous.

Comment: In my eyes this is a "primarily opinion-based question". Because both ways has pros and cons.By the way, in the past I chose often your second way because it generated more clean code (in my eyes).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion first way is better because your pages will be clean and more readable. That'is very important! ;)

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

There's a third way that I think takes the best of both of your suggestions: An *inline* script tag containing the variables:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        var myLib = {
            sessionID: "${sessionId}",
            [...]
        };
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
[...]
</body>
</html>
```

No separate JSP to write. Just as separated as the second solution in your question, as the JavaScript is tied just to the `myLib`, exactly as the JavaScript in your second solution is tied to the structure of the form.

There's a benefit to your first solution we should call out: It allows the HTML to be cached by the browser (by separating the variables into a separate request, e.g., for the `.js.jsp`). Combining the variables with the HTML (either as above, or the second approach in your question) means the HTML has to be served with caching diminished or disabled.